# jQuery - check if json file exists, if not use another file

Tags: jquery, json

I'm working on a project, where depending on user language, widget loads json file with content in that language. But since there are many languages, I need to check, if json file for that language exists, if it doesn't, need to load fallback json file (english).

My current code:

```
var cookieLang = Cookies.get('language');
widget = "../json/widget_";
ext = ".json";
en = 'en';
lv = 'lv';
ru = 'ru';

if (cookieLang === en){
    json_url = widget + en + ext;
}else if (cookieLang === lv){
    json_url = widget + lv + ext;
}else if (cookieLang === ru){
    json_url = widget + ru + ext;
}

$.getJSON(json_url, function(json){
...
});
```

With current code I get console error /json/widget_ru.json 404 (Not Found) when file doesn't exist.

What is the best way to check if json file exists and without console errors, if doesn't exist load default one?

Comment: ajax operations support several events

Comment: @Elvis check what is the url you are finally hitting to server to get the json file. 404 means the URL endpoint does not exist.

Comment: The url is ok, file doesn't exist on the server. What I need is to check if json file exists before $.getJSON function. If it returns error 404, json_url should be "../json/widget_en.json"

Comment: Instead of $.getJSON use $.ajax to handle your error event https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app using only JS, the the below code will help you

```
var cookieLang = Cookies.get('language');
widget = "../json/widget_";
ext = ".json";
en = 'en';
lv = 'lv';
ru = 'ru';

json_url_default = widget + en + ext;

if (cookieLang === en){
  json_url = widget + en + ext;
}else if (cookieLang === lv){
  json_url = widget + lv + ext;
}else if (cookieLang === ru){
  json_url = widget + ru + ext;
}

$.ajax({
 url: json_url,
 type: "GET",
 statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      $.getJSON(json_url_default, function(json){
        //code here
     });
    }
 },
 success:function(json) {
    //code here
 }
});
```

Comment: OK. I guess it kind of works now. Although I still get console error (404) file doesn't exist.  Did it like this:
`code
$.ajax({

        url: json_url,

        type: "GET",

        statusCode: {

            404: function() {
                json_url = widget + en + ext;
                fotoWidget();
            }
        },
        success:function(json) {
            fotoWidget();
        }
    });`

Answer (score 0):

Implement file checking code on server side. check the below code ( if your app in PHP ).

**Client side**

```
var cookieLang = Cookies.get('language');

$.get('/json.php', {lang: cookieLang}, function(json){
    //code here
}.'json');
```

**File :** json.php

```
<?php

   $cookieLang = $_GET['lang'];

   $widget = "../json/widget_";
   $ext = ".json";

   $json_url_default = $widget . 'en' . $ext;

   $json_url = $widget . $cookieLang . $ext;

   if(file_exists($json_url))
     echo file_get_contents($json_url);
   else
     echo file_get_contents($json_url_default);

   exit;
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately my app uses only JS. :(